# What cipher requires the full message to solve

Tags: decryption, pen-and-paper

I am working on a scavenger hunt and wanted to encode a clue in a cipher that requires the full message to decipher. My goal in this is to prevent players from predicting the result before obtaining all the letters of the clue. If possible it would be nice if the cipher could be solved on paper but, beggars can't be choosers.

Comment: For pen-and-paper (and possibly for any cipher) you'd need a lightweight last operation to show the entire message, otherwise you would have to decrypt piecemeal, which is what you try to avoid. Why not use a Caesar cipher or something similar for the last step, and display the key at the end of the decrypted plaintext? Then you just need a cipher that *ends* with a specific value. Note that, in practice, people will give up before getting there though.

Comment: Would it be feasible to have a web page that they access via smartphone?  If so, that opens up a lot of possibilities.

Comment: If you know any webpages that do this or the process for creating a cipher like this (I might be able to program one) that would be great!

Comment: In cryptography what you're looking for is called an _all-or-nothing transform_.

Comment: Thank you! The all-or-nothing transform is what I was looking for!